# jQuery scale effect with callback

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm needing to do an animation that will shrink a div and its contents until it disappears completely.

I can do this fine by using the scale effect, but I need to run some code once the animation is complete, and I can't find a way to specify a callback when using a jQuery effect.

I can find a way to specify a callback function for the jQuery animate method, but none of the animate options seem to offer the effect that "scale" does.

Is there a way to either:

1. specify a callback function when using "effect("scale")"
2. perform a scale effect using ".animate"

Comment: The context of the animation I'm wanting is that I have some items inside different tabs, and when I perform an action on an item that will move it from the current tab to another, the item should shrink (and eventually disappear) towards the tab it is being moved to.

Comment: The callback functions for both `.effect()` and `.animate()` are the same as most other jQuery functions, please read the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/ https://api.jquery.com/animate/